# Downgrade wkhtmltopdf from version `0.12.5 (with patched qt)` to `0.12.4` on Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

We are using `wicked_pdf` gem to generate PDF file from HTML in rails application. This gem uses `wkhtmltopdf` utility. For PDFs generated at server there are some junk characters appearing. But on my local machine (version 0.12.4) it is working ok. I suspect it may be due to problem in wkhtmltopdf version `(0.12.5 (with patched qt))` installed on server.

How do I downgrade from `0.12.5 (with patched qt)` to `0.12.4` ?

Since this is to be done at server I would preferably need most precise answer.

Server OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`

Answer (score 0):

Older releases of `wkhtmltopdf` are available on the GitHub project, under [releases](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/0.12.4/).

From there you can download the `wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-platform.tar.xz` file, then decompress and place it in a bin directory in your PATH, or even inside your Rails application if desired (you can point WickedPdf's `exe_path` at it).

It's hard to say without more information, but I suspect your issue isn't actually related to a `wkhtmltopdf` version difference, but in my experience, it sounds like maybe your server doesn't have the system font packs installed to display with the fonts specified in your HTML, and the resulting PDF, but you often do have them installed on your desktop machine.

Comment: No wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-platform.tar.xz there, only wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-i386.tar.xz

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Thanks. I meant `platform` to mean either `i386` or `amd64`, etc.

Comment: Sorry. I think there is no 64 bits? From `wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf` I get: `wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit The binary is definitely there, but it does expect some dependent libraries are installed on the system to take advantage of its features. Looks like you need to install X or XVFB. Likely you also need some fonts, libjpeg, libpng also.